# escape sequence behaving differently in function

Tags: zsh, function, escape-characters

I’m trying to create a ls-like function.

I started with this alias, which works fine:

```
alias l="/usr/bin/ls -lF --color=always | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 9-"
```

However, converting it to a function results in no colors:

```
l() {
    local _c=
    [ -t 1 ] && _c=--color=always
    /usr/bin/ls -lF $_c "$@" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 9-
}
```

Even removing all differences from the alias to the function remains colorless:

```
l() {
    /usr/bin/ls -lF --color=always | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 9-
}
```

The only colored variant is one without oipe

```
l() {
    /usr/bin/ls -lF --color=always
}
```

What prevents the color from passing through the pipes in functions?

Comment: All functions, and the alias, work fine for me. You can check with `which l` if the command `l` is indeed the desired function. Aside from that, it looks you are trying to extract just the file names from the long output of `ls` to create an output where each file is listed on its own line. If so, the option `-1` (the number "one") might be of interest to you: `ls -1F --color=always`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you haven't got an `l` alias that is either interfering with the function definition or being used before the function: aliases take precedence over functions. And are expanded even for a function definition.

Comment: that was it, thanks. I didn’t know this tidbid, and prezto has an alias that is hilariously similar to what I thought was creative for “l” [`ls -1A`](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/blob/4f19700919c8ebbaf75755fc0d03716d13183f49/modules/utility/init.zsh#L93)